# How can I align my flair at right side?

Tags: support, flair

I want to move my flair to the right side of my profile. Is that possible on Stack Overflow? If so, how can I do it?

See the image:

[image]

Comment: Currently there is no way to do that other than typing a bunch of `&nbsp;`s.

Comment: but i saw in some user profile.

Comment: Can you give us an example, like a link to that profile?

Comment: i dont have that user name. but i saw this type of flair in one user profile about 1-2 weeks ago.so that i asked is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can't do this but there are some not so good alternatives like:

- add `&nbsp;`

**OR**

- add 15 dashes (`-`) with spaces between them.

Example:

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - [flair here]
```

Comment: i already tried this but no change.thnx for suggestion

Comment: @MD - `&nbsp;` [works fine](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/187824/hims056). And IINM this is the only option we have as [we only support a very strict subset of HTML](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/187824). And `align` attribute of `<p>` tag is not supported as well.

Comment: @Mr_Green let me try again

Comment: @Mr_Green ohh my god! it's working. thank you very much.